# recv() with errno=107:(transport endpoint connected)

Tags: c++, network-programming, posix

well..I use a typical model of epoll+multithread to handle massive sockets, that is, I have a thread called epollWorkThread that use epoll_wait to handle i/o sockets. While there's an event of EPOLLIN, recv() will do the work and I do use the noblocking mode to allow immediate return. And recv() is indeed in a while(true) loop.
Everything is fine in the intial time(maybe a couple of hours or maybe minutes or if I'm lucky days), I can receive the information. But some time later, recv() insists to return -1 with the errno = 107(ENOTCONN). The other peer of the transport is written in AS3 which makes sure that the socket is connected. So I'm confused by the recv() behaviour. Thank you in advance and any comment is appreciated!

Comment: No answer, because I don't know what's going on, but try a network monitor to get more information.  I use tcpdump or wireshark, whatever is more convenient.  Don't forget to check your code to see whether corruptions could have caused this problem (valgrind).

Comment: thank you for your information. I tried tcpdump, but failed to know how to capture the packets. I tried "tcpdump -i eth0 'port myportnum'" but it won't capture anythin...

Comment: Are you sure about eth0? Check with "ip addr". Have you tried it as root? Maybe you don't have the right permission.
The parameters are alright, although I also add -s0 and -wtrace.cap so I can view it with wireshark.

Comment: try some more sophisticated sniffer like Ethercap or Wireshark. TCPDump is a very limited tool and difficult to use properly without experience.

Comment: well..using tcpdum, I tried "tcpdump -s 0 -w file 'port myport'" and also "tcpdump -i eth0" and many other combinations of parameters; using wireshark I can only use it as root,when it tells me that it's dangerous. Using wireshark as normal user turns out no interface could be investigated.Seems I have to learn more...anyway, thank you all. (BTW, I use archlinux and Ethercap is unavailable from the mirror)

Answer (score 5):

Errno 107 means that the socket is **NOT** connected (any more).
There are several reasons why this could happen. Assuming you're right and both sides of the connection claim that the socket is still open, an intermediate router/switch may have dropped the connection due to a timeout. The safest way to avoid such things from happen is to periodically send a 'health' or 'keep-alive' message. (Thus the intermediate router/switch accepts the connection as living...)=